# Configuring the Raspberrypi3 and Microstack GPS

Tags: pi-3

I am trying to configure the Raspberrypi3 and Microstack GPS to communicate correctly for my class project. I need a step by step process. Is there a setup guide I can download?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing Microstack host PDF documentation on their site [here](http://www.microstack.org.uk/assets/gps/FormattedGPSgettingstarted.pdf) (PDF), and have further documentation on their Github page [here](https://github.com/microstack-IoT). The PDF includes a hardware connection guide, and a full list of all the Linux commands you'll need to run to install the necessary packages and do some basic testing of the module using Python.

To (very) briefly summarise the docs:

> ***Installing/Setting up:***
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install python3-microstacknode
> sudo apt-get install gpsd gpsd-clients python-gps
> sudo apt-get install raspi-config
> raspi-config
> ```
>
> - From the menu choose Advanced Options.
> - Then choose serial.
> - When asked “would you like a login shell to be accessible over serial?” choose
> - A message saying “serial is now disabled” will appear.
> - Exit raspiconfig and reboot the Raspberry Pi®.
>
> ***Automatically starting gpsd at boot***
>
> ```
> sudo dpkg-reconfigure gpsd
> ```
>
> - Choose  when asked if you want to start gpsd automatically.
> - Choose  when asked “should gpsd handle attached USB GPS receivers automatically”.
> - When asked which “Device the GPS receiver is attached to”, enter /dev/ttyAMA0.
> - Accept the defaults for other options.
>
> ***Run a basic Python test:***
>
> ```
> python3 /usr/share/doc/python3microstacknode/examples/gpscat.py
> ```

Comment: Once I enter "sudo dpkg-reconfigure gpsd", I get a Warning: Stopping gpsd service, but it can still be activated by:gpsd.socket Creating/updating gpsd user account...